# RMySQL - Minhas querys retornam uma lista

Tags: sql, r, mysqli

Olá, estou trabalhando com um banco de dados que costumo acessar com o workbench. Para começar a importar diretamente no R, eu estou usando a biblioteca RMySQL . Consigo fazer a conexão e encontrar as minhas tabelas, mas na hora de importar com o tbl ele me retorna uma lista . Como eu posso fazer para ele me retornar um df (objeto tabela1 no exemplo)?

Exemplo:

```
con <- src_mysql(dbname = "dbname", 
                          host = "localhost", 
                          port = 3306, 
                          user = "user",
                          password = "my password")

tabela1 <- tbl(con, "tabela1")
```

Tentei também o comando *dbReadTable* , mas ele me retorna uma mensagem de erro:

```
*Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dbReadTable’ for signature ‘"src_dbi", "character"’*
```

Agradeço pela ajuda!

Answer (score 0):

Nunca usei esse pacote. Mas o pacote DBI funciona pra mim:

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(dbname = "dbname", 
                          host = "localhost", 
                          port = 3306, 
                          user = "user",
                          password = "my password")

tabela1 <- tbl(con, "tabela1")
```

Comment: Eu tentei conectar com esse pacote mas ele me retorna outro erro esquisito: "Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dbConnect’ for signature ‘"missing"

Comment: Acho que dei o pacote errado. Esse eh um especifico pro servidor que a gente usa. O pacote que eh mais generico eh odbc ao inves de RMySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui solucionar o meu problema!

```
library(RMySQL)
library(dbplyr)


conexao <- dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(),
                     dbname = "name",
                     host = "localhost",
                     port = 3306,
                     user = "user",
                     password = "my password")


# Encontrar uma tabela em duas etapas:

rs <- dbSendQuery(conexao, "SELECT * FROM tabela1")
d1 <- dbFetch(rs)
```